# Can I extrapolate from the progress reporting in MyISAM ALTER?

Tags: mysql, performance, myisam

I'm migrating a 300 million row MyISAM table to add some indexes.

Just because it might be relevant, here's my `ALTER` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX my_table_abcd (a, b, c, d), 
    ADD INDEX my_table_abc (a, b, c), 
    ADD INDEX my_table_c (c), 
    ADD INDEX my_table_ce (c, e), 
    ADD INDEX my_table_d (a);
```

It currently says

```
Stage: 1 of 2 'copy to tmp table'   74.8% of stage done
```

and the processlist says that the progress of the `ALTER` statement is `37.440`.

I don't remember the exact timings, but the 'Stage 1' value jumped up to 60% in the first hour or so, and has been I crawling up to 70% in the last 12 hours. In the lat 3 hours it has increased 1.5%.

I have a decision to make about whether I abort this and try changing some configuration settings or let it run. It's not linear based on previous observations. If it's slowing down exponentially then it's a waste to let it continue when I could be trying another approach.

Any ideas for bases on which to make a decision?

NB [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/581/is-create-index-in-mysql-a-linear-operation/2729#2729) is relevant but not a duplicate. I'm not asking about predicting the time, I'm asking about whether the progress report has a linear relationship with time.

Answer (score 0):

You have redundant indexes

Instead of your `ALTER TABLE`

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX my_table_abcd (a, b, c, d), 
    ADD INDEX my_table_abc (a, b, c), 
    ADD INDEX my_table_c (c), 
    ADD INDEX my_table_ce (c, e), 
    ADD INDEX my_table_d (a);
```

you only need to two of the indexes

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX my_table_abcd (a, b, c, d), 
    ADD INDEX my_table_ce (c, e);
```

To verify this, download [pt-duplicate-key-checker](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-duplicate-key-checker.html) and run it against your table, and you will see its recommendation to remove those three redundant indexes. See my post [Mysql might have too many indexes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87450/mysql-might-have-too-many-indexes/87453#87453) on how to do this.

BTW, that [old post of mine you cited](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/581/is-create-index-in-mysql-a-linear-operation/2729#2729) no longer applies because MySQL now applies all structural changes into a single temp table before loading the data into it.

As for the operation itself, please abort it and start over with my shortened version.

Comment: Thanks for your index advice. I may have confused the MySQL indexes with that of other DBs (or misunderstood). *However*, I think the 'copy to tmp table' stage happens before the actual index-building happens? Is this true? If so, if I re-run this am I heading for another multi-day 'copy to tmp table'?

Answer (score 0):

The progress report is very likely to be non-linear.  This is because of the way caching and sorting work.

Initially, everything can happen in RAM, and this is much faster than on disk.  As things progress, I/O needs to be performed.  Then the I/O gets more involved.

Also, there is an issue of whether it decides to build the index(es) in RAM (in the key_buffer) versus throwing things on disk and using the OS's sort command ("Repair by sorting").  (The latter is faster for huge tables.)  Either way, the progress is non-linear.  The key_buffer eventually fills up and thrashes.  The sort is Order(N
* log N).

I don't think there is much parallelism when adding multiple indexes in a single ALTER.  However, batching the ADD INDEXes saves reading the data multiple times.  So, you were right to do a single ALTER.  Newer versions of *InnoDB* have algorithm=online wherein a single INDEX can be added with *much* less impact on the table.  In this case, doing the ADDs separately *may* be better.

I agree with Rolando on getting rid of the redundant indexes.  INDEX(c,e) can handle "WHERE c=12" (and no mention of `e`).